# Metal blending alpha under 0.5

Tags: graphics, metal

When I try to blend with a color with an alpha of 0.5 or below, metal seemingly discards the color like it has an alpha of 0. When I set the alpha to 0.51, I can see it fine. When I set it to 0.5, it's invisible. Here is a simple implementation of the issue:

```objc
@implementation Renderer
{
    id <MTLDevice> _device;
    id <MTLCommandQueue> _commandQueue;

    id<MTLLibrary> defaultLibrary;
    id <MTLBuffer> _vertexBuffer;
    id <MTLBuffer> _indexBuffer;
    
    id <MTLRenderPipelineState> _pipelineState;
}

-(nonnull instancetype)initWithMetalKitView:(nonnull MTKView *)view;
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        _device = view.device;
        view.colorPixelFormat = MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm_sRGB;

        _commandQueue = [_device newCommandQueue];
        [self _createRenderObject];
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)_createRenderObject
{
    Vertex verts[4] = {
        simd_make_float2(-0.5f, -0.5f),
        simd_make_float2(0.5f,-0.5f),
        simd_make_float2(0.5f,0.5f)
    };

    uint16_t indices[3] = {0,1,2};

    _vertexBuffer = [_device newBufferWithBytes:&verts length:sizeof(verts) options:MTLResourceStorageModeShared];

    _indexBuffer = [_device newBufferWithBytes:&indices length:sizeof(indices) options:MTLResourceStorageModeShared];
    
    // Create Pipeline State
    defaultLibrary = [_device newDefaultLibrary];
    MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor *pd = [[MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor alloc] init];

    pd.vertexFunction = [defaultLibrary newFunctionWithName: @"VertShader"];
    pd.fragmentFunction = [defaultLibrary newFunctionWithName: @"FragShader"];
    pd.alphaToCoverageEnabled = YES;
    
    MTLRenderPipelineColorAttachmentDescriptor *cad = pd.colorAttachments[0];
    cad.pixelFormat = MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm_sRGB;
    cad.blendingEnabled = YES;
    cad.alphaBlendOperation = MTLBlendOperationAdd;
    cad.sourceAlphaBlendFactor = MTLBlendFactorSourceAlpha;
    cad.destinationAlphaBlendFactor = MTLBlendFactorDestinationAlpha;
    cad.rgbBlendOperation = MTLBlendOperationAdd;
    cad.sourceRGBBlendFactor = MTLBlendFactorSourceAlpha;
    cad.destinationRGBBlendFactor = MTLBlendFactorOneMinusSourceAlpha;

    NSError *error = NULL;
    _pipelineState = [_device newRenderPipelineStateWithDescriptor:pd error:&error];
}

- (void)drawInMTKView:(nonnull MTKView *)view
{
    id <MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer = [_commandQueue commandBuffer];

    MTLRenderPassDescriptor* renderPassDescriptor = view.currentRenderPassDescriptor;

    id <MTLRenderCommandEncoder> renderEncoder =
    [commandBuffer renderCommandEncoderWithDescriptor:renderPassDescriptor];

    [renderEncoder setFrontFacingWinding:MTLWindingCounterClockwise];
    [renderEncoder setCullMode:MTLCullModeBack];
    [renderEncoder setRenderPipelineState:_pipelineState];

    [renderEncoder setVertexBuffer:_vertexBuffer offset:0 atIndex:0];

    [renderEncoder drawIndexedPrimitives:MTLPrimitiveTypeTriangle
                                  indexCount:3
                                   indexType:MTLIndexTypeUInt16
                                 indexBuffer:_indexBuffer
                           indexBufferOffset:0];
    

    [renderEncoder endEncoding];

    [commandBuffer presentDrawable:view.currentDrawable];
    
    [commandBuffer commit];
}
@end
```

Shader.metal:

```cpp
typedef struct {
    float4 position [[position]];
} VertexOut;

vertex VertexOut
VertShader(const uint vertexID [[vertex_id]],
            constant Vertex *vertices [[buffer(0)]])
{
    VertexOut out;
    Vertex v = vertices[vertexID];
    
    out.position = (float4){v.position.x,v.position.y,0,1};
    return out;
}

fragment half4
FragShader(VertexOut in [[stage_in]])
{
    return half4(1,1,1,0.50f);
}
```

With that code, specifically the FragShader having 0.50f as the alpha value, I get a blank canvas:
[image: triangle not visible]

If I change the alpha value to 0.51f:

```cpp
fragment half4
FragShader(VertexOut in [[stage_in]])
{
    return half4(1,1,1,0.51f);
}
```

I then get this:
[image: Triangle visible]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It *sounds* to me that somewhere you have "alpha test" enabled with the alpha test threshold set to 0.5, though not having used metal, I couldn't say for certain.  Perhaps you could try asking on https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Thank you @simon-f, your suggestion led me to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. The problem was that [alphaToCoverageEnabled](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlrenderpipelinedescriptor/1514624-alphatocoverageenabled?language=objc) was set to true, while the render target texture type was NOT [MTLTextureType2DMultisample](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtltexturetype/mtltexturetype2dmultisample?language=objc). It appears the two work in tandem, but it's beyond my understanding how.

If not using multi-sampling, set alphaToCoverageEnabled to false.

Otherwise, make sure the render target is of type MTLTextureType2DMultisample.

If using MTKView, set the render target texture type by setting the [sampleCount](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metalkit/mtkview/1535991-samplecount?language=objc) on the MTKView object:

```objc
    _view = (MTKView *)self.view;
    _view.sampleCount = 2;
```

and the render pipeline descriptor of the pipeline state:

```objc
    MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor *pd = [[MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor alloc] init];
    pd.sampleCount = 2;
```